# Oracle SQL using CASE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT (
        SELECT DATE'2021-08-31' - MIN(DATE)
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE BAL LIKE '237%'
        ) AS DATE_DIF,
       ( SELECT SUMM
         FROM TABLE
         WHERE DAT = DATE'2021-08-31' AND BAL LIKE '237%'
         ) AS SALDO_PASSIVE
FROM DUAL;
```

Output is like

| DATE_DIFF | SALDO_PASSIVE |
| --- | --- |
| 837 | 3263200 |

I have tried to use CASE before SUMM but it did not work. Here Date difference = 837 it is between 2-3 years, So output should be SUMM * 0,4.
Or is there another way to do that?

Comment: What is the purpose of CASE in this case?

Comment: For example SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_DIF > 730 AND DATE_DIF < 1095 THEN SALDO_PASSIVE*0.4 ELSE SALDO_PASSIVE END

Comment: ok, so you have (quite unclear) question and an answer... What is the problem? Otherwise make sure you clearly explain the question.

Comment: SALDO_PASSIVE should change according to DATE_DIF

Comment: Please, provide your current code that "doesn't work" and describe what exactly "doesn't work" means. Also please provide sample data and desired output to clarify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only mentioned the logic if year is between 2 and 3. If there are other conditions then you need to mention in case statement.

```
select
DATE_DIF,
(case DATE_DIF/365 between 2 and 3 then SALDO_PASSIVE*.04 else SALDO_PASSIVE end ) SALDO_PASSIVE

(
  SELECT (
        SELECT DATE'2021-08-31' - MIN(DATE)
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE BAL LIKE '237%'
        ) AS DATE_DIF,
       ( SELECT SUMM
         FROM TABLE
         WHERE DAT = DATE'2021-08-31' AND BAL LIKE '237%'
         ) AS SALDO_PASSIVE
  FROM DUAL
);
```